# Difference between a perpendicular vector and a vector perpendicular to the projection

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology, projection

Consider the following paragraph from p5 of [this material](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Evenkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/book-chapter-4.pdf)

> Now, choose a basis $w_1,w_2$ of $W$ so that $w_2$ is perpendicular to
> $v_1$.  If $v_1$ is perpendicular to $W$, any unit vector in $W$ will
> do as $w_2$.  If not, choose $w_2$ to be the unit vector in $W$
> perpendicular to the projection of $v_1$ onto $W$.

It is saying the following points

1. $w_2$ is perpendicular to $v_1$
2. $w_2$ is perpendicular to the projection of $v_1$ onto $W$.

Are they both same? If yes, how can $w_2$ perpendicular to $v_1$ and to $v_1$'s projection on $W$?

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same. Choose $v_1=(1,1,1)$ and consider $W$ to be the span of $w_1=(1,0,0)$ and $w_2=(0,1,0)$. Now the projection of $v_1$ onto the subspace spanned by $(1,0,0)$ is simply $(1,0,0)$ which is orthogonal to $w_2$ but $v_1 \cdot w_2 = 1 \neq 0$ so they are not orthogonal.